# Disabled attribute not being removed when checkbox is unchecked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script below will add the `disabled` attribute to other input fields when `#alt_hp` field is checked, but when I uncheck the field, the disabled attribute does not get removed.  I am not that versed in javascript and tried to make sense of other solutions on this site.

```
<script>
$("#alt_hp").change(function() {
    if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is( ":checked" )) {
        $("#new_displacement").val('')
        $("input#induction, input#heads, input#camshaft, input#turbo, input#boost, input#inc_displacement").prop("checked", false).prop("disabled", true)
    } else {
        $("input#induction, input#heads, input#camshaft, input#turbo, input#boost, input#inc_displacement").prop("disabled", false)
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change below line

`if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is( ":checked" )) {`

to this

`if ($(this).is(":checked")) {`

Your existing code will always refer to `any/all` checkbox in the whole html. `this` refers to the current checkbox/element.